# How to get back to Excel home/welcome screen?

Tags: ms-office

When I first open Excel, I get a handy screen with “Recent,” Template, and “Sign In” options, among other things. I don’t know what this window is called, though I guess it could be called a home screen or welcome screen or something.

When I open a document, this screen goes away. Is there a way to get it back without having to quit Excel and start it back up again?

[image]

Comment: PS: With a worksheet open, there’s also a Home icon in the Quick Access toolbar on the left side of the titlebar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo2JY.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File -> New from Template -> Select "Home" from the sidebar